# Unable to use .size() .div() methods inside pandas groupby with lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm using the following lines of code to compute the conditional probabilities

```
    variable = 'variable_name'
    probs = df.groupby(variable).size().div(len(df))
    cond_probs = df.groupby([variable, 'has_income']).size().div(len(df)).div(probs, axis=0, level=variable)
```

Those results in the following output:

```
    varibale_name         has_income
    (0.999, 2.0]          False          0.756323
                          True           0.243677
    (2.0, 3.0]            False          0.798372
                          True           0.201628
    (3.0, 16.0]           False          0.809635
                          True           0.190365
```

I would like to add an additional column to the output as the size of the sample for each group, but I'm not able to rewrite the formula inside the lambda function because the group object doesn't have the same methods as the objects returned by **df.groupby()**.
Example:

```
    cond_probs =df.groupby([variable, 'has_income']).apply(lambda x: 
    pd.Series({
        'probs': x.size().div(len(df)).div(probs, axis=0, level=variable),
        'size': x.size()
    }))
```

> Error: TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not callable

Are there any alternative to achieve these results in a fancy way, without computing two groupby and joining the data frames at the end?

Comment: Have you tried `x.size` instead, without parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `apply` with `groupby`, you don't get a group object, but a slice of the dataframe that corresponds to the relevant group. So `x` in your case is a DataFrame, not a `GroupBy` object - treat it the same you'd treat `df`.

```
cond_probs = df.groupby([variable, 'has_income']).apply(lambda x: 
  pd.Series({
    'probs': (len(x) / len(df)) / probs[x.iloc[0][variable]],
    'size': len(x)
  })
)
```

**NB** if you use `.size` on a dataframe, it will return the total number of cells - so it's not the same as `GroupBy.size` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html))

Comment: Hi Ruben thank you for your reply, unfortunately len(x) / len(df) returns a scalar on which i can't call the methods .div(probs, axis=0, level=variable)

Comment: I updated the answer to divide by probs, you don't need to do this within a dataframe, as `x` should always be just one value anyway